# Android Calender Provider call startActivityForResult() and get id or some identifier

Tags: android, android-calendar

can we use `startActivityForResult()` method? and get some result back from Calendar Provider for new Event ? like an `id` perhaps to retrieve and edit the event when needed?

Answer (score 0):

you can't open startActivityForResult() for calendar activity but if you want  calendar id that will be able available to you at run-time like this

if you have eventuri which you getting inserting event in calendar provider , you can fetch eventID as below..

```
long eventID = Long.parseLong(eventUri.getLastPathSegment());
```

hopefully this will help you.